Do I need Proof of Residence and German Health Insurance before applying for a student visa as a Non-EU student?
I am from India and I will be applying for a student visa this July 2024.
As per German Missions in India (see link), I need the following "proofs" for Visa Application:

Transcripts, CV, Motivation Letter, Language Certificates, APS Certificate.
Proof of admittance to the study course/preparatory college
Proof of Funds:

Blocked Account (€ 11,208)
Additional Funds (i.e., university tuition fees, additional costs, etc.)


Proof of Insurance:

German health insurance (private / public)
Travel Insurance



In addition, I have income tax returns, work experience certificates and bank documents.
My Questions
Q1. Student Accommodation : I have not found any student accommodation in Stuttgart yet. During Visa Process, do I need to submit "Proof of Residence" in Stuttgart, Germany?
Will my student visa be rejected if I cannot submit any such proof of residence? Or can I continue looking for accommodation after I get my student visa?
Also, is there any option for getting "short stays" (1 week to 1 month) in Stuttgart so that I can look for student accommodation after I reach there? Will such "short stays" be accepted as Proof of Residence during visa process?
UPDATE: The Application Form (see link) taken from the German Missions of India has a Section "Lebensunterhalt und Aufenthaltsdetails" ("Means of support and details regarding the stay")
Q2. Health Insurance : Do I need to get a private German Health Insurance before applying for visa? Or should I get it after I reach Germany?

Where do you see the requirement for proof of accommodation? Are you receiving a stipend from German government/public funding agency?

@xngtng The Application Form (link added in the post) is asking for "Lebensunterhalt und Aufenthaltsdetails", where I have to add "Straße", "Hausnummer", "Postleitzahl", "Ort" and a question with options "Wie werden Sie untergebracht sein?".

@xngtng I am not receiving any stipend from German government / public funding agency. I will be creating a Blocked Account ("Sperrkonto") for proof of funds.

The form states falls bekannt (if known) for street and house number. Q2: after you get the visa and have arrived in Germany.
